# Creating a docker volume from a remote unraid server (samba)

Tags: docker, ip, vpn, samba

I am trying to create a volume for my docker applications. My docker application would need to access a folder that is located on a unraid server (SMB). I can access my remote folder from my windows 10 computer using a VPN. Note the the server is located on a different IP address as my local computer.

I created the following docker-compose.yml file as follow :

```
services:
  Test:
    image: python
    volumes:
      - database:/database

volumes:
  database:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: "username=username,password=password,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0"
      device: "//my.server.ip.address/Database"
```

Now as I am logged into my windows VPN and run `docker compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build`, I get a

```
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_database/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //xxx.xxx.x.xx/Database:/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_database/_data, data: username=xxxx,password=xxxx,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0: permission denied
```

I have tried many of the the proposed solution on the internet, namely trying different version, different file mode or dir mode but I am still stuck.

Does anyone has a solution for this ? Should I install a VPN from inside the docker container to have access to the folder ?

Does anyone has an idea where the issue could come from ?